# Вподобайка навпаки

Tags: переклад, from-english, відповідник

У братів Капранових почув переклад іменника `like` (той, що ставиться, коли сподобалось YouTube відео) як `вподобайка`. Дуже подобається переклад.
А от як так само добре перекласти `dislike`?

Comment: [Попереднє запитання користувача](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/3532) закрили (на мій погляд — цілком дарма). Я не знаю, чи саме тому оце нове запитання спершу було створено в [ме́ті](//ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com) (підсайті для технічних обговорень), а не в [основному розділі](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com), чи це просто випадковість, але сподіювася, цього разу спільнота буде уважнішою до відвідувача.

Comment: я чула "невподобка" на ютубі, але то ж народне джерело :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
вподобайка       | вподобати
-----------------------------------
нагана/наганка   | наганити
докір/дорікайка  | дорікнути
картайка         | скартати
```

Чудове джерело синонімів можна знайти на [Гороху](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%8F/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8).

Мені поки найбільше до вподоби *картайка*.

Answer (score 1):

Мені особисто для *like* найбільше подобається не *вподобайка* (бо воно доволі довге, і також може викликати асоціації не лише з *уподобати*, а й із *уподібнитися*), а *схвалька* (альтернативи: *схвалик*, *схваль*). Тоді *dislike*, відповідно, буде ***несхвалька*** (альтернативи: *несхвалик*, *несхваль*).

Також [на «Словотворі» пропонують](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/dyslaik) спроби створення негативних форм саме від слова *вподобайка*: ***невподобайка***, ***розподобайка***, ***невподоба***.

Також там же пропонують багато інших цікавих варіантів: ***ганик***, ***негожик/негожка***, ***поганик***, ***незгод(ь)ка***, ***несподобка***, ***фе/фу***, ***незгодлик***, ***заперечлик***, ***нехотійчик/небажайчик*** (а також варіантів, що передають радше не загальну негативну оцінку, а певну емоцію: *гидлик/відразка*, *(роз)дратуйка*, *сумлик/жальчик/журбайлик/журлик/нерадійчик/смутик*, *гнівик/обур(ь)ка*, *супротивка*).

Comment: Якщо ви таки вирішили зробити повноцінну відповідь, навіщо тоді було decline мій флаг про вашу попередню спробу напів-відповіді через коментар?

Comment: @bytebuster, це непов'язані речі: (1) тему напіввідповідей у коментарях ми підіймали неодноразово й не дійшли до спільної думки; на StackExchange загалом вони точно не заборонені, а у випадку конкретно UkrainianSE, я вважаю, така можливість просто необхідна; я не знаю такого, щоб це було причиною вилучення коментаря; (2) подивився на відповідь Yola і згадав, що хотів написати трішки більше.

Comment: мені здається, що в англійській мові *dislike* має більше виражений негатив ніж *не схвалювати* в українській. Гадаю, що парою могли б бути ***схвалити/засудити***, але не *схвалити/не схвалити*.

Comment: Схвайлик/засудлик -- схвалити/засудити.